# ASP.NET controls won't see value changes made client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, telerik

I have the following code:

```
function OnClientLoad(sender, args) {

    $telerik.$(sender.get_inputElement()).on('keyup', function (e) {
        var autoComplete = $find("<%= RadAutoCompleteBox1.ClientID %>");
        var contents = autoComplete.get_inputElement();
        var oe = contents.value
        document.getElementById('hdnParameter').value = oe;
    }
}

<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="RadAutoCompleteBox1" ClientID="RadAutoCompleteBox1" 
    autopostback="true" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="edesc" DataValueField="ecode" InputType="Token" Width="100%" Visible="true"
    AllowCustomEntry = "false"
    DropDownWidth="300px"
    OnClientLoad="OnClientLoad"
    >
</telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>

<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False"
ConnectionString="<%$ Myconnectionstring %>"
SelectCommand="exec MyStoredProcedure @parameter">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hdnParameter" Name="parameter" PropertyName="Value" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:hiddenfield id="hdnParameter" runat="server" ></asp:hiddenfield>
```

the SQLDataSource is used to fill the Telerik Ajax AutoCompleteBox dropdown list. So the idea is that when user types in the AutoCompleteBox the value typed be used to feedback the SQLDataSource itself. It's not hard to do as I use the keyup event to capture what is typed and to send it to hidden field value so it SHOULD do the trick.

The problem is that because SqlDataSource and hidden field are runat="server" the updates made in client side will only be seen in client side: if I console.log the value of the hidden field the value is there, but the controls cannot see this. If instead I update the hidden field from code behind the controls see the changes without any problem.

There is a way of working around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Until postback occurs then code behind can't see anything. And any ajax call again means code behind can't see controls until page has posted. If you modify a control client side and THEN do a postback, then code behind will of course see any control value you changed client side. There is not a existing web page copy sitting server side. All codebehind values - code + variables etc. are 100% out of scope ONCE the round trip occures So post back - code behind runs send page back down to client. At this point code behind is out of scope and can't see anything until a new post back occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The data source for your AutoComplete should only be a binding data source if you know at design time all the possible suggestion values, which is a pretty narrow use case. You need to connect up your autocomplete to an AJAX data source instead. The Telerik documentation has an example of how to do this [here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/autocompletebox/data-binding/binding-to-web-service)